# Como pasar 2 variables "GET" por URL?

Tags: php

Tengo este formulario en el que un usuario escribe un comentario y este se envía a la misma pagina y el comentario aparece uno debajo de otro la persona solo puede comentar 1 vez da un error amarillo de que ya ah comentado etc... (Todo perfecto pero sucede algo).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Le eh agregado el boton rojo que es un **"a href" Borrar**...

Sucede que antes tuve el problema con este  **$_GET que aparece hasta arriba en este código** ... Sucede que es el  **$_GET** con el que voy recogiendo la **ID** 2 paginas antes (Todo bien).

Entonces ocurrió que cuando use un formulario con el boton AZUL para **ENVIAR** el mensaje alguien me sugirio que pusiera un **input hidden** con la variable **$_GET['id']** para que cuando el formulario se **enviara el mensaje hacia la misma pagina pues encontrara por URL la variable** (Todo bien)

El problema es que ahora cuando trato de enviarle **OOootra** variable por el metodo **GET** y en el botón de "BORRAR" pues este primer **$_GET['id']** "No lo encuentra" y me sale un error...

Cabe decir que estoy tratando de pasarle por URL esta parte (Es donde **Pinto los comentarios** donde dice OJOOOOO) **href='reporte_erroes.php?idBorrar=$i[IDUsuario]** para precisamente darle la opción al usuario de que borre su comentario.

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:

**Es posible enviar 2 variables por URL con el metodo $_GET" para evitar este problema?** O cual es el tipo de solución entonces...

En pocas palabras necesito una variable llamada **?idBorrar** (La del botón borrar)
y otra llamada simplemente **?id** (La del botón enviar)
Gracias por cualquier ayuda.

```
               $_GET['id'];


            if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
                echo "<div class='bg-white col-lg-7 col-sm-12'>";



                /* Si se presiona ENVIAR recogo lo que se ENVIO*/
                if (isset($_GET['comentario'])) {
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO comentarios_nes(IDUsuario,IDJuego,UsuarioName,Comentario) VALUES ('$_SESSION[ID]','$_GET[id]','$_SESSION[user]','$_GET[comentario]')";

                    //$sql = "UPDATE  contenidones SET IdComentarios = '$_GET[comentario]' WHERE ID = '$_GET[id]' "; 


                    $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


                    if ($resultado == true) {
                        echo "<div class='bg-white col-lg-7 col-sm-12'>";
                        echo "Tu comentario se a enviado, gracias";
                        echo "</div>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<div class='bg-warning col-lg-12 col-sm-12 rounded-top'>";
                        echo "El comentario no pudo enviarse<strong>o bien
     ya has comentado</strong> (Edita tu comentario o trata mas tarde)";
                        echo "</div>";
                    }
                }
                /* ---*/



                /* Aqui consulto una tabla COMENTARIOSNES */
                $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM comentarios_nes WHERE IDJuego = '$_GET[id]'";
                $resultado2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
                $datos = [];
                while ($hileras = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado2)) {
                    $datos[] = $hileras;
                }
                /* ---*/



                /* Esto es el FORMULARIO*/

                echo   "<form>";
                echo       "<div class='form-group'>";
                echo           "<input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Deja un comentario' name='comentario'> ";
                echo            "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='$_GET[id]'>";
                echo           "<small id='emailHelp' class='form-text text-muted'>Comentario de no mas de 150 caracteres</small>";
                echo      "</div>";
                echo       "<button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'  >Enviar</button>";
                echo      "</form>";


                /* ---*/

                /* Pinto los COMENTARIOS*/
                foreach ($datos as $i) {
                    echo       "<div  class='bg-light mt-2' ><img src='/Imagenes/Iconos/icono_reporte2.png' width=20 height=20>";

                    echo       "<strong class=''> $i[UsuarioName]</strong>:";

                    echo        "$i[Comentario]";

                    /* En este IF compare si el ID de la sesion es igual al ID del comentario USUARIO ---IDUsuario--- para hacer que aparezca el boton BORRAR*/
                    if ($_SESSION['ID'] == $i['IDUsuario']) {
                        echo       "<a class='bg-danger btn-borrar' href='reporte_erroes.php?idBorrar=$i[IDJuego]' >Borrar</a>";
                    }
                    /* ---*/
                    echo        "</div>";
                }
                echo       "</div>";
                /* ---*/
            } else {
                echo "<div class='bg-white col-lg-7 col-sm-12'>";
                echo "<p class=''>Inicia sesion para acceder a esta sección</p>";
                echo       "</div>";
            }
```

---

Imagenes NUEVAS:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: me parece que aquí: `$i[IDJuego]` te faltan una comillas así:  `$i['IDJuego']` y si quieres enviar dos parámetros escríbelo así por ejemplo: `href='reporte_erroes.php?idBorrar=$i['IDJuego']&IDusuario=$i['IDUsuario']'`

Comment: @masterguru Edite la pregunta al final puse 2 comentarios mas, ya se como expresarlo fijate aqui que el problema (Me doy cuenta) en efecto NO es enviar 2 variables si no que al presionar el href el nombre de mi variable es **idBorrar** y ya no **id** que es la que se envia con el value del boton enviar del formulario ¿Te fijas?:


**"<input type='hidden' name='id' value='$_GET[id]'>"** ---Y-----------------

**href='reporte_erroes.php?idBorrar=$i[IDJuego]&IDusuario=$i[IDUsuario]**

Lo que necesito es tener 2 nombres de variable (Me estoy dando cuenta)

**2 VARIABLES no 2 PARAMETROS**

Comment: Un **href**  en una etiqueta `<a>` actua de forma independiente del formulario, es simplemente una URL, y cuando hablas de **variables** en un GET viene a ser lo mismo que yo llamo **parámetros**, pues cuando lleguen al archivo PHP destino se van a convertir en variables reales cuando hagas algo asi como `$variable=$_GET['idBorrar'];` (y justo en ese momento, los **parámetros** de una URL se convierten en **variables** dentro del PHP)

Comment: Por otro lado, si tu pregunta es cómo se mandan varias **variables** (que yo llamo parámetros) por GET en una URL que esta en un href, la respuesta es _concatenandolas mediante el símbolo **&**_, tal como puse en mi primer comentario de ejemplo.  Ahora siéntete libre de cambiar las **variables** (parámetros) de la URL por las que tu quieras y con los valores que desees y tantas como necesites mientras las separes con **&**

Comment: @masterguru eh puesto unas fotos para expresarme de mejor manera **aunque creo** que estoy equivocado y **tú en lo cierto** estoy analizando bien lo que me comentaste porque parece que como que en efecto se **resuelve** con lo que citas...

Comment: **No** lo pongas así:  `href='reporte_erroes.php?idBorrar=$i[IDJuego]&$_GET['id']"`  sino así:  `href='reporte_erroes.php?idBorrar=$i['IDJuego']&id=$_GET['id']'`  (y mejor que cortes y pegues lo que acabo de poner porque aun no habias ni corregido las comillas que te habia dicho en mi primer comentario)